# what is the radius of convergence of power series $\frac{z^2}{z}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have a power series and am being asked to find its radius of convergence, but its structure of type $$\sum\frac{z^{2n}}{z^n}$$ is confusing me. How do I calculate radius of convergence of this power series?

Comment: Is it the actual question as in your text book?

Comment: Do you really mean $z^2/z$?  That's $z$, which is a polynomial and has radius of convergence $\infty$.

Comment: oh i'm sorry! my mistake. Actually its Z^2n/Z^n

Comment: $\frac{z^{2n}}{z^n} = z^{2n - n} = z^n$, which is known (geometric series) to converge when $|z| < 1$

Comment: yes it is convergent. but what is its radius of convergence?

Comment: If it converges for $\vert z \vert \lt R$ then it's radius of convergence is $R$

Comment: but its given that its radius of convergence is square root 2.

Comment: what is the general term of the series?

Comment: summation Z^2n/Z^n. n is from 1 to infinity.

Comment: Isn't the series $\sum_n \frac{z^{2n}}{2^n}$?

Answer (score 3):

the series $$\sum_{n} \frac{z^{2n}}{z^n} = \sum_n z^n$$ is convergent for every $z$ with $|z|<1$.

It diverges for $z = 1$. Therefore the radius of convergence of this series is $1$

Similarly, (in case of a typo in your question) the series $$\sum_{n} \frac{z^{2n}}{2^n} = \sum_n \left(\frac{z^2}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n$$ is convergent for every $z$ with $|z|<\sqrt{2}$.

It diverges for $z = \sqrt{2}$. Therefore the radius of convergence of this series is $\sqrt{2}$(see 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence)

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow the inequality in your last line. Shouldn't you just be summing over even $n$?

Comment: Why do you say so?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't dropped a factor of $2$ somewhere when you go from $\frac{z^{2n}}{2^n}$ to $\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n$?

Comment: Indeed @AndrewLedesma thank you